# Can you paraphrase "How long do we give it" in the excerpt below?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, synonyms

I'm still developing my English so it's great if you answer my question in a very short and direct way; the shorter it is, the better.
I don't get the meaning of "HOW LONG DO WE GIVE IT" in the excerpt below. (Edit: thank you. ..I can't search where to reply..)

> Does any man strive to gain wealth or influence for any reason other than to reach a point where they can abuse with impunity those under their control? **How long do we give it** before we start treating anyone who wants to become rich, famous or powerful in any way as automatically suspect?

Answer (score 1):

"How long do we give it" means "how long do we wait". We can have a long time as well as a long distance.